# hide category list in side position when same list is shown in main position

Tags: joomla2.5

through the menu I let my users visit a page with list of articles in a certain category (let's call it startpage). In a position left to the main position I display the same list of category articles. That makes sense if the user picks one of the articles, because he still can see the other articles in the same category. But how can I hide the category list in the sidebar when the user is still on the startpage?

Best Regards,
Sascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is not easy because no one knows the real structure of your site. You can define where this module (I hope its one) is placed. For example you can only show it in categories where the article belongs to. Then you've hide it out from the startpage.

If the "startpage" isn't the real startpage and for example an overview of the categorie and you want only show this menu when an article is opened by a user I don't belive that you can do this with standard joomla possibilities. Therefor you can install an extension like [Advanced Module Manager](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/modules-management/10307) where you can precisely define when a module is shown or not. For example: Only in articles, with dependencies on time and date, categories, menues, ...

Comment: The Advanced Module Manager (amm) did the trick. I had to configure my mod_articles_category module with amm to be shown only within the configured category with page type article (you can find the setting und module configuration when you edit the module).

Answer (score 0):

Go to module manager > module article category (for the list you want to hide on the home page).

At the bottom left of this window under menu assignment, deselect the home page and save.

If the have the home page in more than one menu, you may need to repeat this for each menu.

Good luck!